# Dictionary<string, object> serialization

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

My data class contains Dictionary field for some highly diverse data.

```
internal class Program
{
    public class DTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dictSerializer = new DictionaryInterfaceImplementerSerializer<Dictionary<string, object>>(DictionaryRepresentation.Document);
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<DTO>(cm => cm.MapMember(dto => dto.Data).SetSerializer(dictSerializer));

        var instance = new DTO
        {
            Name = "test",
            Data = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"str", "thestring"},
                    {"byte", (byte)42},
                    {"bytearray", new byte[]{ 0x1, 0x2, 0x3}}
                }
            };

        var col = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017").GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<DTO>("test");
        col.InsertOne(instance);
    }
}
```

And I got:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56a9eeeacdc5b3ea38c0a522"), 
    "Data" : {
        "str" : "thestring", 
        "byte" : {
            "_t" : "System.Byte", 
            "_v" : NumberInt(42)
        }, 
        "bytearray" : {
            "_t" : "System.Byte[]", 
            "_v" : BinData(0, "AQID")
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, "byte" and "bytearray" fields serialized with discriminators "_" and "_v".
But I expect something like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56a9eeeacdc5b3ea38c0a522"), 
    "Data" : {
        "str" : "thestring", 
        "byte" : 42,
        "bytearray" : BinData(0, "AQID"))
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to serialize with Newtonsoft ? I think Newtonsoft will create an output something like you expect.

Comment: I agree with @CihanUygun. Newtonsoft is the best choice in such cases. Alternatively, you could your own `DictionaySerializer` instead of `DictionaryInterfaceImplementerSerializer`

Comment: Why do you want the second entry to be just `"byte" : 42` ? how will it know that `42` is a byte? Because your data has types, hence the they "_t" (DataType) and "_v" (DataValue).

What would be the difference between `"byte" : 42`, `"int" : 42` and `"key" : 42` ?

Comment: The .NET mongo driver attempts to keep type fidelity. String doesn't need a discriminator because, well, it's a string. However, there isn't a native type in MongoDB for byte, and therefore, to ensure that when it's read back from MongoDB, it comes back as a byte, we must add a discriminator. If newtonsoft does what you are asking, then the .NET driver (and probably newtonsoft) will read it back as an integer, because that's what it looks like. So, if it's important that it's a byte, then  you'll need to just stick with the .NET driver.

Comment: @SollyM difference in keys is enough for me. All I want - serialize my data in beautiful and easy-to-find format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible to use Newtonsoft for Serializing and Deserializing your object, Newtonsoft is the best solution for Serialization operations. Can you please try the code below ?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DictionaryTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public class DTO
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var dictSerializer = new DictionaryInterfaceImplementerSerializer<Dictionary<string, object>>(DictionaryRepresentation.Document);
            //BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<DTO>(cm => cm.MapMember(dto => dto.Data).SetSerializer(dictSerializer));

            DTO instance = new DTO
            {
                Name = "test",
                Data = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"str", "thestring"},
                    {"byte", (byte)42},
                    {"bytearray", new byte[]{ 0x1, 0x2, 0x3}}
                }
            };

            string serializedOne = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance);

            var col = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017").GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<DTO>("test");
            col.InsertOne(serializedOne);
            Console.WriteLine(serializedOne);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I'm not a MongoDB expert and I remember that I was succesfully done an operation in past something like that.

Newtonsoft.JSON Official Page: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Newtonsoft.JSON NuGet Page: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Hope this helps you

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Thank you! Your code actually doesnt compiles, are you meant that?
string serializedOne = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance);
var col = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017").GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test");
col.InsertOne(BsonDocument.Parse(serializedOne));

Comment: You welcome, as yes probably you need to insert BsonDocument directly it was long time the last time I used MongoDB server and I do not remember `col.InsertOne` part clearly.